# How do I get an "App Store URL" to begin integrating ads from mobile networks?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm trying to take a peak at the few ad networks that have Native ad options. mopub and avocarrot to name a couple.

I notice they want an "App Store URL" to proceed through the very first part of signing up.

I don't have an App Store URL yet though. My first app is 95% done (just have ads and IAP's left). So I'm not ready to submit my app to the app store yet.

How can I get an App Store URL without submitting my app to the app store?